# Google Cloud Platform - Data Fusion - Wrangler

Tags: csv, join, google-cloud-platform, record, directive

I am trying to join two input sources in the Google Cloud Platform, one from BigQuery and the other from Google Cloud Storage which contains a .csv file. I see using a joiner is the best option.

But I am curious whether the same can be achieved using the table lookup: column 'table' directive. The input records will be from BigQuery, and the 'table' will refer to the .csv file in Google Cloud Storage. Is it possible to achieve this with just Wrangler without using joiner?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes, you can use Wrangler instead of joiner to connect two data sources, you can apply basic transformations and export this information into a sink in Google Cloud Platform.

For your specific scenario using BigQuery for the input records and the 'table' from the .CSV file contained in Google Cloud Storage please check this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/targeting-campaign-pipeline#before-you-begin) which contains the specific steps on how to achieve it.

Comment: @Nadhiya If this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.